# Error in UseMethod("count"): no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Tags: r

I'm really new to R and I have encountered the error above when running my code for Q6:

- **Question 5:** Write a function that simulates $X_n$ for a given party size $n$. That is, your function should take the party size $n$ as input, shuffle the hats (i.e., a vector of IDs), then count how many people got their hat back and return this count as an output. \newline Hint: The `sample` or `sample.int` functions may be useful for this exercise.

```
#Replace with your code for Question 5
hat_problem <- function(n) {
  x <- 1:n
  set.seed(123)
  x_n <- sample(x)
  count(which(x == x_n))
}
```

- **Question 6:** Simulate $X_n$ 1,000 times for $n=30$ and plot a frequency barplot of the (simulated) distribution of $X_n$ (either using `ggplot2`, or the base R `plot`, up to you). \newline Hint: The `replicate` function will be useful for this exercise, though an `sapply` or a `for` loop would also work.

```
#Replace with your code for Question 6
hat <- replicate(n = 1000, hat_problem(30))
ggplot(hat, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar()
```

Did I misuse the replicate() or count()? How should I fix it?

Comment: Yes, you should use `sum(x == x_n)` Or `length(which(x == x_n))`.

Comment: Each Stack Overflow post should focus on one specific programming question at a time. Please do not combine unrelated questions.